# What show am I remembering about aliens taking over Earth?

Tags: alien-invasion, story-identification

I think in this show aliens have taken over the earth and essentially humans are working with/for them - but although things seem better the aliens are really farming people for food. I remember three specific scenes/plot lines and I believe both are from the same show: there is some sort of maternity/fertility clinic and video billboards urge women to come to it; there is a teen or young woman who is pregnant and some character close to her tells her not to go to that clinic; there is a woman (doctor? scientist?) maybe working at this clinic and she discovers the doctor is involved with giving the babies to the aliens. Next scene - a lower level area (maybe in clinic) is discovered where people are being processed - hanging on hooks like cattle; there is a fight there as good guys try to save people and stop this.

Last scene, people are sent (voluntarily?) to what is supposed to be a good place to live and work, maybe sold as sort of a farm or something, and good guys discover it the people who go there are killed; I think they have to show the facility to someone who does not believe this is happening.

I can't remember any actors, and my googling efforts have run out of key words etc. It is NOT "V" - I think I saw this within the past few years, should be something made between 2000 and 2017. I am sure I watched it as home, and it was more likely a series or miniseries than a feature film. Maybe a short lived series?

Comment: TV Tropes as examples of alien man-eater stories, but none of them are obvious fits:  http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Toserveman

Comment: There was a Twilight Zone episode that also featured “humanitarian” aliens, but the details don’t quite match up.

Comment: Substitute "vampires" for "aliens" and it sounds like The Strain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Strain_(TV_series), on FX from 2014-2017; there were several scenes in the last season that prominently featured the human-cattle processing line, clinics for pregnant women (from the Partnership), and a farm.

Comment: Is it possible it was a show based on a book of sorts? I vaguely remember reading something like this. I'll try to see if anything comes up.

Comment: Joelogon - you may be right. Yesterday I started redirecting my thoughts from alien to other possibilities and I thought of The Strain. I am now thinking that I am remembering a mix of scenes from The Strain and The Lottery series (the one that only lasted one season and was all about infertility/fertility with a clinic and evil doctor etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Joelogon! I just read recaps of Season 4 of The Strain and everything fell into place. I had a few random images from The Lottery series mixed into my memories which had caused me additional confusion. But bottom line is the bad guys were Strigori vampires, not aliens - plus a few human baddies. So glad to be able to stop obsessing about this now!!!
Thanks to all who gave input!

Comment: Thanks Brythan; I clicked it.

Answer (score 6):

The V TV series was remade in 2009 and aired until as it turns out until 2011. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1307824/ It is the only series that I know of that covers an alien invasion of Earth in order to use humans as a food source. I will continue to do some research but I am unaware of any other such series being made other than V. First in 1984 and then again in 2009.

Comment: Here is an episode list for 2 seasons. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1307824/episodes?season=1 Look it over and see if it rings any bells. I could be wrong, but I still feel this is what you are remembering.

Comment: I have skimmed over the episode descriptions (thanks for the link) looking for any key words that go with my memories and no bells have rung; I'll probably look again at the longer descriptions. I had already looked at images from the series just to be sure - no bells there either or images that go with my recollected scenes. So far other than the aliens invading and turning out to be human-eaters, there seem to be no other similarities to what I recall. If you know of any specific scene(s) that match, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: I'll keep my eyes open.